# How do make jquery .each loop wait for response?

Tags: jquery, callback, aws-lambda

How do I make an iteration in a .each loop wait when I call a second function that calls a script in AWS and is waiting for a response from AWS?
This is my .each loop:

```
$('.subscriptionStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
    var sku = $(this).attr('data-sku');
    subscriptionStatus(sku, function(response) {
        var messageDiv = $(this).closest('.subscriptionMessage');

        var innerHtml = '';
        if (response){
            innerHtml = 'Successful';
        }else{
            innerHtml = 'Failed';
        }
        messageDiv.html(innerHtml);
    }//wait until 
}
```

for each iteration I'm calling a function, inside i'm calling a script in AWS Lambda and need to wait for its response and then continue the iteration:

```
function subscriptionStatus( sku, callback ){
    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
    lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'MyFunction',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({
            "sku":sku
        })
    }, function(err, data){
        //response from AWS Lambda

        var success = data.Payload;
        if( success == 'true'){
            //NEED TO PASS TRUE BACK TO THE CURRENT ITERATION OF THE EACH LOOP
            callback(true); //correct way?
        }else{
            //NEED TO PASS FALSE BACK TO THE CURRENT ITERATION OF THE EACH LOOP
            callback(false); //correct way?
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that the iterations aren't waiting. 
What's wrong in my code?

Comment: You would have to stop using .each, because it's never gonna wait on an asynchronous action.

Comment: I don't mean this to be condescending or anything like that, but you should totally read this article: http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/02/01/what-color-is-your-function/ it's a super funny portrayal of the problem you're having here.  The problem is basically that you're calling an async function inside of a synchronous loop.  So the only way is to block on each call in the loop until it returns.  It looks like lambda functions have new support for synchronous execution, but the documentation was vague: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/getting-started-custom-events.html

Comment: @Milimetric You said " So the only way is to block on each call in the loop until it returns." How can I do that?

Comment: @Miss_poker you can't... unless lambda has a synchronous option. note however that said option would result in your application freezing for the duration of the loop, including all css animations, gifs, loading bars, and user interactions.

Comment: @KevinB so instead of .each is there something else I can use?

Comment: A recursive function should do. a function that calls itself after the asynchronous action is complete with a reference to the next item in the array.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks Kevin, i'll try that out

Comment: @Miss_poker: the docs I linked to were the only thing I found while searching but I'm not very familiar with lambda.  If you can hit AWS with plain AJAX, jquery has an async: false option: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.  Basically, you'd have to find the same kind of behavior in lambda or to change your logic to be ok with async responses (which is also possible, just keep a list of results and append to it whenever AWS gives you a callback).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with Promises and Deferreds (in jQuery)

what your code would be is roughly:

```
function subscriptionStatus( sku ){
    var $dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
    var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();
    lambda.invoke({
        FunctionName: 'MyFunction',
        Payload: JSON.stringify({
            "sku":sku
        })
    }, function(err, data){
        if( data.Payload == 'true'){
             $dfd.resolve();
        }else{
            $dfd.reject();
        }
    });
    return $dfd.promise();
}
```

you can now do:

```
subscriptionStatus(<sku>)
    .done(function() {

    }).fail(function() {

    });
```

Now for the fancy part: how to implement this in your .each loop? It depends if it needs to be in the correct order OR if you just have to wait until they are all finished. if you just have to wait for all of them to finish in no particular order:

```
// no particular order
var deferreds = []; // does nothing yet
$('.bla').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $msgDiv = $this.closest('.subscriptionMessage');
    var sku = $this.attr('data-sku');
    var $dfd = subscriptionStatus(sku)
       .done(function() { $msgDiv.html('Successful'); })
       .fail(function() { $msgDiv.html('Failed'); });
    deferreds.push($dfd);
});
jQuery.when.apply(jQuery,deferreds)
    .done(function() { alert('all successful'); })
    .fail(function() { alert('any of the requests was not succesful'); })
    .always(function() { alert('they are all done'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this to work? I see another issue with your code that doesn't have anything to do with Lambda. The value of `this` in your callback that you are passing to subscriptionStatus won't be a `.subscriptionStatus` element. So most likely `messageDiv` is always an empty jQuery object. You could log it out to verify.

To fix it, save a reference to `this` in the `.each()` like so:

```
$('.subscriptionStatus').each(function(i, obj) {
  var _this = $(this); // save reference
  var sku = _this.attr('data-sku');
  subscriptionStatus(sku, function(response) {
    // now _this has a reference to the actual jQuery object wrapping the .subscriptionStatus element
    var messageDiv = _this.closest('.subscriptionMessage');

    var innerHtml = '';
    if (response){
        innerHtml = 'Successful';
    }else{
        innerHtml = 'Failed';
    }
    messageDiv.html(innerHtml);
  }//wait until 
}
```

I suspect this will fix your problem unless you truly want to block until each response comes back(which will hurt render time). If thats the case, you should look into Promises.